# Spacing on nav bar when hover

Tags: html, css, nav, spacing

I have a problem with the navigation bar. When I hover over About or Text on the nav bar it shows a spacing on the left side of the button, I want it the hover colour to contain the full width of the button.

https://jsfiddle.net/jdd3h0sf/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="nav">
<ul> 
    <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Text &#8964;</a>
      <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li></li>
        </ul>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact &#8964;</a>
        <ul class="submenutwo">
            <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Three</a></li></li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
#nav { 
    background-color: #333;
    height: 52px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav li  {
    border-right: 1.8px solid #191919;
    height: auto;
    width: 156.5px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.home  {
   border-left: 1.8px solid #191919;
}
#nav ul li { 
    display: inline-block;
}
#nav ul li:hover { 
    background-color: #444;
}
#nav ul li a, visted { 
    color: #ccc;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li a:hover { 
    color: #ccc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul { 
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #444;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-top: 0;
    max-width: 169px;
}
#nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
#nav ul ul li a:visited {
    color: #ccc;
}
#nav ul ul li a:hover {
    color: #2980B9;
}
```

Comment: Hi QTRLDN, welcome to Stack Overflow.  You don't need to add 'I found a solution' to your question.  Just accepting the answer (green tick) that helped solve your problem is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a part of `display:inline-block;`. If you want to keep them displayed `inline-block`, there are several different solutions [(Read a css-Tricks article about it)](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/):

## 1 - Change your HTML format:

Change your `<li>`'s html like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   one</li><li>
   two</li><li>
   three</li>
</ul>
```

Or this:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li
  ><li>two</li
  ><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Or even with comments, like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li><!--
  --><li>two</li><!--
  --><li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Or, just place all the li's on a single line:

```
<ul><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li></li>
```

It is messy, yet effective.

## 2 - Negative margins:

Pretty straightforward:

```
li{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}
```

## 3 - Skip the closing tag:

This is actually perfectly fine in HTML5, li's do not have to have a closing tag.

```
<ul>
  <li>one
  <li>two
  <li>three
</ul>
```

## 4 - Set the `<ul>`'s font size to 0:

```
ul {
  font-size: 0;
}
ul li {
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

## 5 - Or, just float the `<li>`'s:

Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: Found this interesting. I like your first option, but in my personal opinion, I think simply placing the list elements in one line would be the cleanest: `<li></li><li></li>`. But regardless, very interesting to see workarounds to keep the elements on separate lines.

Comment: @goatmeal lol, thank the guys at css-tricks :D I only knew of the first and second option before I read that article

Comment: @JacobGray Thanks #4 works well for me! My webpage is XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You are experiencing the [dreaded inline-block spacing issue](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). In your fiddle, if you condense all of your `li` elements to be on the same line, the hover works as expected. The linked article outlines a few other options.

You can also just `float` the elements and that would resolve the issue.

```
#nav ul li { 
    float: left;
}
```